# Int64 converted value of BitArray is coming different with "SetAll" . Any reason?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

In the first scenario, (below) the final integer value is 255 (used `BitArray.SetAll(Boolean)`)

In the second scenario, the final integer value is 3 (which is correct. set the bits for each index.)

My expectation is both should behave same. But not. Any specific reason?

**Scenario 1:**

```
BitArray myBA = new BitArray(2);
myBA.SetAll(true);            
byte[] byteArray = new byte[8];
myBA.CopyTo(byteArray, 0);
Int64 finalInt = BitConverter.ToInt64(byteArray,0); //finalInt = 255
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
BitArray myBA = new BitArray(2);
myBA[0] = true;
myBA[1] = true;
byte[] byteArray = new byte[8];
myBA.CopyTo(byteArray, 0);
Int64 finalInt = BitConverter.ToInt64(byteArray,0); //finalInt = 3 (which is expected.)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code on [.netfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net):

```
BitArray myBA = new BitArray(2);
myBA.SetAll(true);            
byte[] byteArray = new byte[8];
//myBA.Length++;
myBA.CopyTo(byteArray, 0);
Int64 finalInt = BitConverter.ToInt64(byteArray,0);
Console.WriteLine(finalInt);
```

It prints the wrong 255, however, if you just increase the `Length` before copying to the array (uncomment the commented line), then it prints the correct 3!

This tells me that this is some sort of a bug in the .NET framework. Also, if you you switch the framework to .NET 5 or .NET Core, then you always get the correct "3" even if you don't increase the `Length`.

Looking at the source code for [.NET framework](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/bitarray.cs,19ad3f494f0dc7f6) and [.NET Core](https://source.dot.net/#System.Collections/System/Collections/BitArray.cs,378732114a00fbc8), here's what I think is happening:

In the .NET framework, `SetAll(true)` sets all the `int`s in the underlying `int[]` to `-1` (all 1s), regardless of the `Length` of the bit array. It is only when you increase the `Length` that it "adds" a new 0. `CopyTo` doesn't seem to consider the fact that when the `Length` of the bit array is not a multiple of 8, it should not copy the entire last byte. So it does copy the entire last byte, which is all 1s, producing the 255 that you see.

OTOH, `CopyTo` in .NET Core [does consider this](https://source.dot.net/#System.Collections/System/Collections/BitArray.cs,908):

```
// last byte is not aligned, we will directly copy one less byte
```

And also on line 925:

```
// mask the final byte
```

which suggests copying only a part of the final byte. Also, `SetAll(true)` in .NET Core only sets `myBA.Length` bits to 1 in the underlying `int[]`, and *clears* the rest of the bits that are not aligned with the byte.

Here is the [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/17765) (Thanks to [Matthew Watson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106159/matthew-watson) who found it!) in the .NET Core repository, which seems to be handled now. This probably explains why the bug is not on .NET Core.

Comment: This could be the issue on GitHub that was fixed: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/17765